# How to pass datetime parameter from pipeline to Dataflow in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, google-cloud-dataflow

I want to read file from datalake in dataflow based on datetime filter and I am trying to pass start time from pipeline which getting from sql table.
I tried multiways but not working.

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and expected output? errors/blockers from your approach? what is your start time that you are getting from SQL table?

Comment: I want to pass 1/16/2024 1:00:00 as startDate from ADF to dataflow and source in dataflow will read file from startDate to UTC now

Comment: Ok, so you want to read the file by its last modified date right?

Comment: I just wanted to get datetime when last time pipeline was executed and wanted to read all files which created after last time executed pipeline

Comment: `1/16/2024 1:00:00` are you getting this value from SQL table?

Comment: Yes, In ADF. Pipeline

Answer (score 0):

As you are getting the required date from SQL table, use a lookup with **FirstRow** on your SQL table to get that value.

Convert the required value to correct date format with below expression using a string type set variable activity. Here, I have passed a hardcoded date value, in your case it will be `@activity('lookup1').output.firstRow.<date_column>` in below expression.

```
@convertToUtc('1/16/2024 13:00:00','UTC')
```

[image]

This will be converted to UTC format, but it will be still string only.

[image]

In Dataflow, create a string type parameter.

[image]

Use this parameter in the `StartDate` of the source with below expression.

```
toTimestamp($mydate,'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss','UTC')
```

[image]

Also, as you want to transform multiple files, add a wildcard path like above.

Add your respective sink. Here, I have given ADLS gen2 for sample.

Now, in pipeline, pass the pipeline variable using pipeline expression to the Dataflow parameter like below.

[image]

These are sample input files in the `temp` folder.

[image]

Execute the pipeline and you can see only the file `sample2.csv` copied to the target as per the given `UTC`.

[image]